# How did super heroes deal with military drafts?

Tags: superheroes

You've got a multitude of super characters who have been around for a long time.  For example, Superman and Batman debuted in the 1930s.  During that time we've had America participate in WW2, Korea, and 'Nam.  During all of those wars conscription was a reality.  Was it ever addressed in-universe how Superman, Batman, Flash, Green Lantern dealt with the prospect of being drafted?  The problem here is two-fold since each had a civilian identity.  I think that Hal Jordan (GL) might have been a veteran, given his test pilot career, but don't know if this was ever explicitly stated.  In your answers, feel free to address other characters, even from other publishers, other than the examples I've named.

Comment: It's an interesting question, but too open-ended at the moment. Try to restrict it to a specific set of heroes within a specific franchise. I mean, we have some idea how Captain America dealt with it, but that doesn't really provide a good answer here.

Answer (score 3):

This was finally addressed in [All-Star Squadron #4](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/All-Star_Squadron_Vol_1_4). The JLA and various superheroes set out to crush the Axis Powers, but were repulsed by the use of various magics involving the Holy Grail and Spear of Destiny, a situation that continued until the death of Hitler.

[image]

---

As to the specifics of why *Clark Kent* didn't get drafted, he failed his eye test (in the February 15-19, 1942 installments of the ["Superman" newspaper strip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superman_(comic_strip))) and was declared 4-F, unfit for military service.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Bruce Wayne would probably have been declared I-H (deferred) due to his age at the time of the WW2 draft.

Comment: The Flash and Green Lantern were members of The Justice Battalion during WW2. It fought the Nazis regularly (at the request of the US President), so presumably they were given exemptions.

Comment: Lots of body shaming going on in that newspaper strip! At least Superman has the decency to do it sotto voice...